# Evaluating Proportional Hazards with time-dependent variables

Tags: r, cox-model, hazard

I'm doing survival analysis and using the survival package from R to do it. I have 7 variables, 5 of which are time-dependent (all except sexo and peso).

Here is my model:

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(tempo1, tempo2, status) ~ sexo + clima + 
    CODE_06 + TP_media7 + ndvi + peso + epoca, data = newftable)


                        coef exp(coef) se(coef)       z      p
sexoM                -0.1098     0.896   0.5472 -0.2006 0.8400
clima                -0.2368     0.789   0.0731 -3.2408 0.0012
CODE_06Regadio       -0.9961     0.369   0.6532 -1.5249 0.1300
CODE_06Sequeiro      -0.0711     0.931   0.5009 -0.1420 0.8900
TP_media7(12,22]     -0.5616     0.570   0.8064 -0.6964 0.4900
TP_media7(22,32]     -1.0945     0.335   0.8680 -1.2609 0.2100
TP_media7(32,41]      0.0533     1.055   0.9557  0.0558 0.9600
ndvi(3e+03,6e+03]    -0.1502     0.861   0.8386 -0.1791 0.8600
ndvi(6e+03,8.05e+03] -0.7635     0.466   1.0205 -0.7482 0.4500
peso[845,1005]       -0.3257     0.722   0.4961 -0.6565 0.5100
epocamid_inv_rep      0.4414     1.555   0.7077  0.6237 0.5300
epocamid_pos_inv     -0.0722     0.930   0.7601 -0.0950 0.9200
epocamid_rep_pos      0.4424     1.556   0.7770  0.5693 0.5700
epocapos_repr         0.3200     1.377   0.8114  0.3943 0.6900
epocarepr             0.1755     1.192   0.7742  0.2267 0.8200

Likelihood ratio test=28.4  on 15 df, p=0.019  n= 2267, number of events= 30 
   (94 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

I want to test the PH assumption (using cox.zph) only for sexo and peso, since time-dependent variables fail to satisfy this assumption (Kleinbaum & Klein, 2005).

I did:

```
>cox.zph(teste)
                      rho    chisq     p
sexoM                -0.14944 7.14e-01 0.398
clima                 0.19168 9.60e-01 0.327
CODE_06Regadio        0.06300 1.13e-01 0.737
CODE_06Sequeiro       0.24125 2.01e+00 0.157
TP_media7(12,22]      0.21771 1.29e+00 0.257
TP_media7(22,32]      0.26118 1.84e+00 0.175
TP_media7(32,41]      0.20317 9.91e-01 0.319
ndvi(3e+03,6e+03]     0.04029 5.40e-02 0.816
ndvi(6e+03,8.05e+03] -0.04816 7.40e-02 0.786
peso[845,1005]        0.08051 2.82e-01 0.595
epocamid_inv_rep      0.00243 2.26e-04 0.988
epocamid_pos_inv     -0.17620 8.17e-01 0.366
epocamid_rep_pos      0.10899 2.69e-01 0.604
epocapos_repr         0.27081 1.95e+00 0.162
epocarepr             0.09812 2.45e-01 0.621
GLOBAL                     NA 1.12e+01 0.737
```

And it seems that every variable satisfies the assumption (Although I know it's not true). When I have a model only with the 2 time-independent variables, the result is the following:

```
                   rho  chisq     p
sexoM          -0.1797 1.6287 0.202
peso[845,1005]  0.0181 0.0166 0.897
GLOBAL              NA 2.8486 0.241
```

My question is, what is the right procedure?